# MBCS encoding unknown

Tags: python, encoding, mbcs

I'm trying to open a file with MBCS encoding in Python but I'm getting an error.

If I write:

```
fileIN = open(filename, "r", encoding = "mbcs")
```

I get:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/data/stru0039/Rotation/test.py", line 144, in <module>
>    fileIN = open(filename, "r", encoding = "mbcs")
> LookupError: unknown encoding: mbcs
> ```

Is there a way to install this codec? Thanks!

Comment: MBCS is not an encoding, it's a category of encodings, namely those that use a variable number of bytes per character (or a fixed number, usually two). So you need to find out which one your file is using (UTF-8 is the most common one) and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I sorted it now, it was ISO-8859-1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mbcs` encoding is [only available on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). It refers to whatever the current Windows "ANSI" code page (CP_ACP) is.¹

If you are not running it on Windows, just guess an encoding and use it. If you are running it on Windows but through something like MSYS2 or Cygwin, you get a [bug to report](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2275) since someone is failing to detect the underlying Windows API.

---

¹ For those reading this answer, it's probably *not* an MBCS, but just a single-byte encoding like CP1252 (most similar to ISO-8859-1).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu you can either convert the file to UTF-8

filename.encode('mbcs').decode('utf-8')

or change the format with an editor.